# UIWebView locating text by touch

Tags: ios, text, uiwebview, touch, locate

Would like to capture a touch on a UIWebView, map that to the relevant HTML text and insert a hyperlink into the HTML at that point.

Found a very nice reference to cleanly capture touches on UIWebView at:

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

I've implemented it and it works very well.

Also found a very nice reference to search and highlight text in a UIWebView at:

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/

I've implemented it [for a search feature] and it works very well.

But I can't quite make the intellectual jump from touch position [not text search] to a specific word in the UIWebView. Obviously this can be done, since touch-and-hold on a UIWebView triggers a "Copy or Define" popup which obviously knows the specific word you've pointed at.

The individual text nodes that JavaScript decodes from the DOM have no offsetLeft or offsetTop or offsetWidth or offsetHeight; I understand these need to be derived from the parent node.

But the individual text nodes can consist of many lines of text, depending on what the HTML source looks like. Potentially a single text node can contain an entire paragraph of text, hardly the one word that I'm trying to spot.

Can anyone suggest how "Copy or Define" can be so clever? Thanks.